# MySQL Validate Email Records

Tags: php, mysql, validation, email-validation

I know you can use PHP Email Validate filters to check if the data is `abc @ abc . ext`

Is there anyway I can run a MySQL query to do this, check for only that style format. Otherwise I will have to make a pagination and load balanced limit script to select all records from the DB (50,000+) and the server is already slow for my client on shared hosting.

I just want to see a list of only valid emails and also can I check for duplicates or similarities with `like` query?

Appreciate any collab on this.

Comment: this is why we validate data before it goes into the db =\

Comment: My client has only just got XSS protection and also FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL from myself. Just looking for a solution. I am aware of this thanks!

Comment: why do you need pagination for this one-time operation? I don't understand your reasons

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel Hi; I thought that loading 50,000 fields into the browser will bring a large window and crash the server and make it slow. So pagination would reduce that using LIMIT ...

Comment: What is the point in loading 50,000 fields into the browser?! What you gonna do with all them?

Comment: You cleary not understood. That is why I want to do this with MySQL. I said pagination and making a page as a last resort as I could use IF ELSE filters and FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL filters in the PHP WHILE loop. MySQL would be better for me as I can export the data in CSV or XML format... etc..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Somethis like this

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email NOT REGEXP '^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]{2,}$';
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email NOT REGEXP '^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$';
```

Update.
It's just an example,how to use regular expression in Mysql.

Comment: Will this remove www.site.john@site.com or www.hayley.smith@www.mail.com etc - some strange emails! even got empties; mobile numbers, passwords with no MD5 and so many things you can imagine in the email field!

Comment: Yes good idea **Using mysql regex :)** See This Tutorial `http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-regular-expression-regexp.aspx`

Comment: It's just an exmpale how to regex in mysql.You can write your own REGEXP :)

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid: those are both allowable e-mail addresses, I don't see your issue with them.

Comment: ...and dotted quads, and domains with more than 2 parts, and the rest of the chars allowed in a mailbox name...IIRC MySQL uses a POSIX parser - for PCRE, I use '^[a-z0-9\._%+!$&*=^|~#%\'`?{}/\-]+@[a-z0-9\.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$'

Comment: No such thing. I can't find the reference here for sarcasm. But upped your comment regardless. @Col.Shrapnel

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid: No such thing? How's life back in the year 2000? The `.museum` domain has been introduced in 2001, along with `.travel`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.museum From where I stand, that's *ten years* ago.

Answer (score 12):

You can use something like this

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE email_col LIKE '%@%.%'
```

to get (quite) valid emails, excluding the ones that are wrong for sure.
But you should check results to be sure of what you're showing...
Anyway, this is a starting point...

Comment: Plus one for the effort, I have used this as additional query compiler for the above.

Comment: Yes because I used this for quick validation and removals in addition to the above. I think I will make a PHP page too just to be sure I get clean emails and together with the new sign up forms. This would be the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Run this SQL to create trigger inside mysql database, This will prevent inserting wrongly formatted email:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `users_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `users` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF (NEW.`email` REGEXP '^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$')=0  THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '[table:users] - `email` incorrect format!';
    END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you can use a regex to validate the emails but with limited accuracy.

```
-- you could, but not recommended
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email NOT REGEXP '^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]{2,}$';
```

You may find it better to use a service like [Real Email](https://isitarealemail.com) to validate the emails, which not only checks if the email looks correct, but if the domain and account are valid.

You could export your data as a csv then validate it. For more see [How to validate emails in an sql database](https://docs.isitarealemail.com/how-to-validate-email-addresses-in-an-sql-database).

Answer (score -1):

Use this one, it will check where should be an '@' and '.' in the email.
This is tested one.

SELECT * FROM `school` WHERE `email` NOT REGEXP 
'^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9.*-]*[a-zA-Z0-9.*-]@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$';

Comment: Dont use this. Too many false positives using this regex. emails like foo-foo123@foomail.com get caught and it is a valid email address.